# In "create react app" I want to hit an API in dev environment and check the output of the API and based upon that I want to do some configs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

When I run `npm start` I want the server to Hit an api endpoint and get the mode dev/prod.
And that result I want to read into my components.

Same thing I want to replicate in the Production server, In production I am using node with express and in that when the server will start it will hit an endpoint and get the mode dev/prod and based upon that I will do some conf in my components.

Answer (score 0):

You should make an endpoint on the server that returns a simple value. It will be one of the first calls on your client-side. I could not tell if your client app was server-side rendered, in which case the server should make the API call before it even starts rendering pages (ensures it is fully set up)

Or have the landing page of your client side be this simple call, and the result of that call will change routes to the location of your React app. Perhaps the route will indicate what "mode" you are in `/app/dev/#` or `/app/prod/#` or `/app/#?mode=dev`?

Just some ideas.

Comment: I am running in dev mode with hot reloading, not with the server-side. So, I want that it should hit an API before doing the client side reload. I don't want client side should aware of that API and it should be done internally. LIke if I am using express with node there I can do the call and render that UI based upon that

Comment: Are you wanting to watch your hot reload to change on the fly, because your server might be changing while your client dev environment is running? You would have to look at your hot reload tooling. Is that webpack? Typically webpack has build and config options for dev and production environments. You could run in dev or prod mode when you start your client server (this is typically enough), but you could add to the building script your API check and apply that to the build/running environment on the fly. Again, just ideas, if I understand the use case.

Comment: I am using `create-react-app` and it uses `webpack` under the hood, and yes, can you help me to add build script to check API call.

Comment: I cannot help directly, just figure webpack will have a way to do it. Maybe check out https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/ or find an example somewhere? Sorry I cannot help more - it's an innovative idea to me but I've never had to do it! I hope it works out for you, let me know if it it does : )